# Material UI 0.2x compatibility with React 16

Tags: reactjs, express, material-ui, react-dom, react-16

After trying to upgrade from React 15.4 to React 16.4.1 (also upgraded react-dom to 16.4.1) I'm getting this error message from the router:

```
TypeError: _nextProps.children is not a function
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (/var/www/web/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2491:55)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (/var/www/web/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2354:19)
    at renderToString (/var/www/web/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:2726:25)
    at render (/var/www/web/server/routes/others.jsx:141:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

The code:

```
const render = () => {
  const body = renderToString(
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <IntlProvider>
            <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
          </IntlProvider>
        </Provider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

`render` is defined here but returned afterwards in the same routing file:

```
Promise.all(prefetchData(renderProps, store))
  .then(render)
  .catch(prefetchError => next(prefetchError));
```

I followed the [recommended instructions](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#upgrading) in order to upgrade from React 15.x to React 16.x

Since I've found related issues regarding material-ui compatibility with React 16:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8434

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7795

I was wondering if this error message could be caused by an incompatibility between material-ui 0.2x and React 16.x, or in other words, I would like to know if it's necessary to upgrade to material-ui 1.x in order to be able to use React 16.x

Comment: We are using material-ui 0.18.1 with React 16.3 and all is working well. I don't think this error is because of incompatibility between material-ui 2.x and React 16.x.

Comment: Although that's on client side and you are using on the server-side using `renderToString`. So that might be the case.

Comment: https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example#getting-started I found this repo which renders material-ui 0.x on server side with React 16. So it’s definitely not a compatibility issue.

Comment: So it’s not necessary to upgrade material-ui to version 1.x to use React 16.x.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think your third comment can be the accepted answer if you type it as such :)

May be it's an incompatibility regarding only `MuiThemeProvider` from material ui 0.2x, but that would be out of scope of this question I think. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using `material-ui 0.18.1` with `React 16.3` for client-side rendering and all is working well. I don't think this error is because of incompatibility between `material-ui 0.2x` and `React 16.x`.

For server side rendering, I found [this repo](https://github.com/kireerik/razzle-material-ui-styled-example#getting-started) which renders `material-ui 0.x` on server side with `React 16.x`. So it’s definitely **not a compatibility issue**.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently tasked with supporting both MUI 0.x and MUI 1.x and although it was challenging, I found a way to make it work.

With MUI 0.x, I found the versions that worked well together were:

- `material-ui@0.19.4`
- `react@16.3.2` - upgrading to `react@16.4` will break it, something to do with how events are handled in that minor update.

There was some other configuration required to get MUI 1.x working in conjunction with MUI 0.x but hopefully this part is enough to answer your question.